# How to learn multi-class multi-output CNN with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to train a convolutional neural network with TensorFlow to do multi-output multi-class classification.

For example: If we take the MNIST sample set and always combine two random images two a single one and then want to classify the resulting image. The result of the classification should be the two digits shown in the image.

So the output of the network could have the shape [-1, 2, 10] where the first dimension is the batch, the second represents the output (is it the first or the second digit) and the third is the "usual" classification of the shown digit.

I tried googling for this for a while now, but wasn't able find something useful. Also, I don't know if multi-output multi-class classification is the correct naming for this task. If not, what is the correct naming? Do you have any links/tutorials/documentations/papers explaining what I'd need to do to build the loss function/training operations?

What I tried was to split up the output of the network into the single outputs with tf.split and then use softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on every single output. The result I averaged over all outputs but it doesn't seem to work. Is this even a reasonable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For nomenclature of classification problems, you can have a look at this link:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

So your problem is called "Multilabel Classification". In normal TensorFlow multiclass classification (classic MNIST) you will have 10 output units and you will use **softmax** at the end for computing losses i.e. "tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits".

Ex: If your image has "2", then groundtruth will be [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

But here, your network output will have 20 units and you will use **sigmoid**  i.e. "tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits"

Ex: If your image has "2" & "4", then groundtruth will be [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], i.e. first ten bits to represent first digit class and second to represent second digit class.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to provide two labels to an image comprised of two different images. Then change your objective loss function so it maximizes the outputs of the two given labels and train your model. I don't think you need to split the outputs.

Comment: Well, my question is how must that loss function look like. Is there a tensorflow method I can call to calculate me this loss function? If not, how would I calculate it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with tensorflow much, but having gone through the tutorial I assume that y_  should simply have few values for one example in  ,say, cross entropy:                                      cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))              Have you tried that? If it does not work, code the cost function yourself with labels being matrix, not a vector. In theano the negative loglikelihood for example would be: T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y]) and I would make y(labels) a matrix with few labels per example.